# プロジェクトを公開・発行する際にターゲットランタイムを指定するとエラーが出る原因

Tags: c#, visual-studio

プロジェクトを公開・発行する際にターゲットランタイムを移植可能にして発行すると正常終了するが、
いずれかのランタイムを指定した際にエラーが出る原因は何が考えられるでしょうか？
環境はWindows10/Visual Studio 2019（16.7.1）です。

追記：
エラー内容
公開でエラーが発生しました。
発行でエラーが発生しました。エラーの原因を特定できませんでした。詳細については、出力ログを確認してください。
＊診断ログも同様の内容

プロジェクトは.Net Core 3.1のWindowsFormになります。
特定のPCでのみ発生するようで、別のPCで同様の設定で発行を行なうと問題なく動作します。

追記２：
ターゲットランタイムの移植可能　…　デフォルト
ターゲットランタイムの指定　…　win-x64やwin-x86

Comment: 支障の無い範囲で、プロジェクトの構成とか正常時/異常時の設定の差、発生しているエラーの詳細などを追記してください。今の質問内容だと具体性が乏しくて助言や回答が難しいでしょう。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。追記いたしました。

Comment: 「ターゲットランタイム」の「移植可能」と「指定」の差はこちらのページ [.NET Core アプリケーションの発行の概要](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/core/deploying/) に書かれている何に該当するのでしょう？ ちなみにPCに依存するということは、必要なランタイムがインストールされているか否かの違いなのでは？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。追記いたしました。win-x64やwin-x86でもエラーが出るので、ランタイムではないと思うのですが…。確認方法はどのようにすればよろしいのでしょうか。

Comment: ちょっと再確認ですが、出来上がったものを別の実行用PCにインストール＆実行する際のエラーでしたか？ それともプログラムを作って配布するために開発用PCでビルド等する際のエラーですか？

Comment: 検索するとこれらあたりが関連しているかも。[Publish Single File (Release) fails for WPF .NET Core 3.1 application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59357765/9014308)/[日本語化](https://www.it-swarm.dev/ja/c%23/813000809/), [Error when trying to publish an azure function from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59205875/9014308)/[日本語化](https://www.it-swarm.dev/ja/visual-studio/812915195/)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。返信が遅くなりすみません。
エラーは開発用PCです。プロジェクト自体はエラーの出る環境で新規作成しています。別のPCはそれをコピーして移動しています。
リンク先の内容確認してみます。

Comment: 色々と試した結果、変わらなかったのでWindowsごと再インストールしたところ動作するようになりました。助言ありがとうございました。